# Order of brace expansion and parameter expansion

Tags: bash, command-precedence

A common trope on StackOverflow [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) is: *"Why doesn't `x=99; echo {1..$x}` work?"*
The answer is *"because braces are expanded before parameters/variables"*.

Therefore, I thought it should be possible to expand multiple variables using a single `$` and a brace. I'd expect `a=1; b=2; c=3; echo ${{a..c}}` to print `1 2 3`. First, the inner brace would expand to `${a} ${b} ${c}` (which it does when writing `echo \${{a..c}}`). Then that result would undergo parameter expansion.
However, I got `-bash: ${{a..c}}: bad substitution` so `{a..c}` wasn't expanded at all.

[Bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) is a bit more specific (emphasis mine).

> Expansion is performed on the command line after it has been split into tokens [...]
> The order of expansions is: **brace expansion**; tilde expansion, **parameter and variable expansion**, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution **(done in a left-to-right fashion);** word splitting; and filename expansion.

<sup>Note the `;` and `,` in that list. "Left-to-right fashion" seems to apply to the whole (therefore unordered) list before the `;`. Just like the mathematical operators `*` and `/` have no precedence over each other.</sup>

Ok, so brace expansion is not really of higher precedence than parameter expansion. It's just that both `{1..$x}` and `${{a..c}}` are evaluated from left to right, meaning the brace `{` comes before the parameter `$x` and the parameter `${` comes before the brace `{a..c}`.

Or so I thought. However, when using `$` instead of `${` then parameters on the left expand *after* braces on the right:

```
# in bash 5.0.3(1)
x=nil; x1=one; x2=two
echo ${x{1..2}} # prints `-bash: ${x{1..2}}: bad substitution`
echo $x{1..2}   # prints `one two`
```

#### Question

- Could it be that the bash manual is flawed or did I read it wrong?
- If the manual is flawed: **What is the exact order of all expansions?**

<sub>I'm just asking because I'm curious. I don't plan to use thinks like `$x{1..2}` anywhere. I'm not interested in *better solutions* or *alternatives* to address multiple variables (e.g. array slices `${array[@]:1:2}`). I just want to get a deeper understanding.</sub>

Comment: I think the bad substitution errors happens because `x{1..2}` isn't allowed according to `valid_brace_expansion_word`. See `subst.c:8781`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html

> **To avoid conflicts with parameter expansion, the string ‘${’ is not
> considered eligible for brace expansion, and inhibits brace expansion
> until the closing ‘}’.**

That said, for `echo $x{1..2}` , first the brace expansion takes place, and then the parameter expansion, so we have `echo $x1 $x2`. For `echo ${x{1..2}}` the brace expansion doesn't happen, because we are after the `${` and haven't reached the closing `}` of the parameter expansion.

Regarding the bash manual part you have quoted, left-to-right order still exists for the expansions (with respect to allowed nested ones). Things get clearer if you format the list instead of using `,` and `;`:

1. brace expansion
2. In a left-to-right fashion:
   tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution
3. word splitting
4. filename expansion.

Comment: Thank you for the quote. That really helps. However, the manual quoted in my question still seems wrong. My interpretation is that braces and parameters have no precedence over each other; whatever is the leftmost thing expands first. Yet in `$x{1..2}` the brace expands first even though there is a `$` on the left (and therefore having precedence over `{ }`).

Comment: Good explanation. This interpretation of the manual didn't cross my mind. With this interpretation, parameter expansion always comes before command substitution. Therefore I'd expect `bash -c 'echo $SECONDS $(sleep 1; echo $SECONDS) $SECONDS'` to print `0 1 0`. But it prints `0 1 1` showing that the last parameter expansion took place *after* command substitution.

Comment: I still don't understand why `$x{1..2}` expands the brace first. With `x=nil` and a left to right evaluation  I'd assume `$x{1..2}` –param. exp.→ `nil{1..2}` –brace exp.→ `nil1 nil2`. I know why I get the results in my question. Because the expansion order is different from what I assumed. This leads us to my question: **What is the expansion order in general**? As we have seen, it is neither a strict *"braces before variables"* nor a strict *"left to right"*.

Comment: Because brace expansion really goes first, in your quoted bash manual text, it's brace expansion`;`, L-R order applies for the next, comma separated, expansions.

Comment: Thank you so much! Finally, things cleared up for me. Up until now I only noticed the last `;` and overlooked the `;` right behind *"brace expansion"*. Now everything makes sense.

Comment: Yeap, the order is that you have quoted. I had also overlooked that semicolon, then I noticed that, but I doubted with your examples, finally all examples are consistent with the manual, so ... we believe. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Read Mo Budlong's 1988 classic *[Command Line Psychology](http://sunsite.uakom.sk/sunworldonline/swol-02-1998/swol-02-unix101.html)*, which was written for regular Unix, but most of it still applies to `bash`.  The order of evaluation goes:

```
1 History substitution (except for the Bourne shell)
2 Splitting words, including special characters
3 Updating the history list (except for the Bourne shell)
4 Interpreting single and double quotes
5 Alias substitution (except for the Bourne shell)
6 Redirection of input and output (< > and |)
7 Variable substitution (variables starting with $)
8 Command substitution (commands inside back quotes)
9 File name expansion (file name wild cards)
```

So what `bash` does with code like `{1..3}` happens before step 7 above, and that's why the OP code fails.

But if we must, there's always `eval`, (which should only be used if the variables are known in advance, or first cautiously type checked):

```
a=1; b=2; c=3; eval echo \{$a..$c}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From this explanation I'd assume that ```bash -c 'echo `sleep 1` $SECONDS'``` would print `0` because the last variable would expand *before* the subshell (rule 7 comes before 8). However, the command prints `1` showing that the variable expanded *after* the subshell. Additionally, the list does not talk about brace expansion at all.

Comment: @Socowi, It's incorrect to generalize about all variables from `$SECONDS`, since it's an *internal* variable, (as opposed to a *user* variable), so it behaves more like a `bash` function.   Consider the following code which stores that internal variable in a user variable: `bash -c 'n=$SECONDS; echo $(sleep 1) $n $SECONDS'` and outputs `0 1`.  See also:  [*How do I use $SECONDS inside a bash script?*](https://askubuntu.com/q/1028924/561230)

Comment: @Socowi, Ordinary shell brace expansion would involve *6 Redirection* and perhaps *8 Command substitution*.  Stuff like `bash`'s `{1..3}` is more like *5 Alias substitution*.

Comment: Of course `bash -c 'n=$SECONDS; anyCommand; echo $n'` always prints `0` because `n` does not update. If there was a distinction between user and special variables in term of expansion order, then that difference had be pointed out in any answer to my question *»What is the exact order of all expansions?«*. Also, I don't see why [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) would involve *6 redirection* or *8 command substitution*.

Comment: @Socowi, Re *brace expansion*:  Sorry, I'd mistakenly used the term ordinary *brace expansion* to refer to command grouping using the `{}` chars, *e.g.* `{echo foo; echo bar;} | tac`.